# Passing images between screens in flutterwith pushNamed

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am using onGenerate route for my flutter app, when I try to pass an image as an argument using push named I default to error page without any error message!!

**Home Screen**

the car has already been initialized in the home screen as `final AssetImage car_image;`

`onTap: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/details', arguments: DetailScreen(data:data ,image: car.car_image));},`

**DetailScreen**

`class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {`

````
final AssetImage image;
DetailScreen({Key key, this.image, this.data}) : super(key: key);```
````

Comment: Do you want to pass the image or only the reference to load it again? Pass only the reference and if you want to make some sort of transition take a look at the Hero widget.

Comment: @racr0x how do i pass the reference?

Comment: Pass the string with the path/name. Im assuming that you just want to pass dynamic content.

Comment: @racr0x the image is also dynamic since its passed from the home screen as car.car_image, not the path

Comment: Actually you should be allowed to pass this image. I think your problem is here: {arguments: DetailScreen(data:data ,image: car.car_image));} . The arguments should be the data and image itself, not an instance of the DetailScreen. Try this out and let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: @racr0x I've tried to pass without an instance of DetailScreen as seen in the second example here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html  But it only expects one positional argument which in our case would be data which is a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help someone in future.
Prefer using named routes as passing arguments through them is much more defined and easy.
In your case define the Details route in your main dart file
DetailsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => DetailsScreen(),
after which from the screen that you are routing from pass the arguments that you need to the Details screen,after that accept the arguments using the
ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic> method,retrieve the data and you are good to go.